# Installing protobuf for Java using Maven

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

I'm kinda new with all these enviromental variables and I have no clue how to install the prebuilt protobuf. The readme suggested the installation of Apache Maven which I've done but after that the readme says that I should put the executable in the src directory.

1. Is this the src directory in protobuf?(Cuz there's no such dir in
   maven)
2. If so what executable should I put in there?
3. Oh and lastly are there any enviromental variables required for proto?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Generally, with Maven or Gradle, you'll use a plugin defined in your build file (POM for Maven), and then the tool takes care of downloading and invoking the plugin like you've instructed.

Comment: Build the C++ code, or obtain a binary distribution of protoc (see
   the toplevel [README.md](../README.md)). If you install a binary
   distribution, make sure that it is the same version as this package.
   If in doubt, run:

     $ protoc --version

   You will need to place the protoc executable in ../src.  (If you
   built it yourself, it should already be there.)


This is step two of installation with Maven but when i type "protoc --version" cmd prompt doesn't recognise it as a command

Comment: That's more of a basic how-to-use-Unix question. You need to learn about command paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven comes with a dependency management mechanism that allows the build to retrieve third party artifacts at build time.  Installing Maven will install the Maven executable, but it is more reliant on plugins (which are delivered using the same dependency mechanism approach via repositories).  If you are using Java and Maven, have a quick read of how the dependencies are declared: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

When you use Maven, you define a Project file (or POM file).  In the project file, you define, in declarative format, the artifacts upon which your project is dependent.  Maven will retrieve those artifacts at the appropriate time of the build.

If your Java program wants to use the Java artifacts for Protobuf, you need to declare the Protobuf artifact details in the POM file.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java

In Maven-speak, that looks like

```
groupId: com.google.protobuf
artifactId: protofbuf-java
version: 3.0.0 (or whatever version you want to use)
```

You don't install these anywhere you've installed Maven.  These declarations are in your POM file, which will be parsed by Maven

Typically, the artifacts are other JAR files.  If you are expecting different binary files types, this might not be the right solution